# How to show a message if there are no products inside a category with exp:resso store plugin?

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

I'm using the latest version of EE2 and a plugin called Exp:resso store.

I have products assigned to a category and for the most part all of this is working fine. Below is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    {exp:channel:categories channel="products" style="linear"}
    <section class="section accordion repeater">
        <h3>
            {category_name}
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/assets/local/img/plus-icon.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            {exp:store:search orderby="title" sort="asc" category="{category_id}"}
                {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                <p class="accordion-download">
                    <a href="#">{title} - {price}</a>
                    <span><a href="#"><img src="/assets/local/img/add-to-cart.jpg" alt="">Add to cart</a></span>
                </p>
                {/exp:store:product}                
            {/exp:store:search}                     
        </div>
    </section>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</div>
```

I'm trying to find a way to show a `No products exist` message if the category doesn't have anything inside of it. I've tried using `{count}`, `{total_results}` & `{total_rows}` to check if there aren't any products. Problem is everything I try is obviously wrong because nothing gets output :/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store search tag is a wrapper for the channel entries tag pair so you would need to use the `{if no_results}` tag pair.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    {exp:channel:categories channel="products" style="linear"}
    <section class="section accordion repeater">
        <h3>
            {category_name}
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/assets/local/img/plus-icon.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            {exp:store:search orderby="title" sort="asc" category="{category_id}"}
                {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                <p class="accordion-download">
                    <a href="#">{title} - {price}</a>
                    <span><a href="#"><img src="/assets/local/img/add-to-cart.jpg" alt="">Add to cart</a></span>
                </p>
                {/exp:store:product}
                {if no_results}
                  There are no products
                {/if}
            {/exp:store:search}                     
        </div>
    </section>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</div>
```

Should also be mentioned if you are not creating a form for the to add the products to the cart you could use the `{store_field_short_name:price}` variable to reduce the number of queries on your page. Most store things such as sku, weight, measurements can all be access by using the field short name followed by `:variable`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'l give this a shot when i'm back in work tomorrow

Comment: No problem, in the future you will probably get more views if you post to the EE specific site http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Comment: Unfortunately this still outputs absolutely nothing to the screen

Comment: You might be running into issues with the nested tags. You might try moving the store search tag to an embed to and passing the category_id as an embed variable.